# How to set textfield minimum characters on swift 3

Tags: swift, string, textfield, uitextfielddelegate

I'm looking for a way to minimize characters in textfield. Since the textfield is for username input, I want to make users input 4 characters minimum to 30 characters maximum. First, I made textfield `shouldChangeCharactersIn` to set maximum characters in textfield. The code looks good but the problem when I want to make users if the username text field is less than 4 characters the app gives them error or to return false.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool { 

let currentString = usernameTextField.text!.characters.count ?? 0
        if (range.length + range.location > currentString) {
            return false
        }
        let newLength = currentString + string.characters.count - range.length
        return newLength <= 30
    }
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 1):

I would implement the `textFieldShouldEndEditing(_:)` delegate method. If the current length is too short, return `false` and optionally present some sort of message/indicator so the user knows what is wrong.

I would also update `textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString:)` to check if the new length is too short. If so, disable a Save button or some other appropriate UI component(s) letting the user know they have something to fix.

Answer (score 1):

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    let fieldTextLength = textField.text!.characters.count

    if  fieldTextLength < 4 || fieldTextLength  > 30 {
        //do something about it
    }
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    return true
}
```

Didn't really understand your problem at the end but this should do it!

Comment: The problem is when any users input usernameTextField less then 4 and greater then 30 characters it's give him a false. I did the last part (greater then 30 character) but I couldn't find a solution for less then 4 characters

Comment: This is not the proper approach. This code still allows the keyboard to be dismissed even if the text field is too short or too long.